# Configuring an apache virtualhost to link to another's virtualhost's subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a domain on my server (on its own virtualhost), e.g. domain.com, which has a lot of subdomains with content on it.

- sub1.domain.com
- sub2.domain.com

This virtualhost looks like this:

> ```
>  ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
>  ServerName domain.com
>  ServerAlias *.domain.com
>  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/
> ```

I want to put other domains on the server and have each of them link to a specific subdomain on domain.com. I don't want it to redirect. I want a similar behavior as the [L,PT] flags on mod rewrite.

I've tried this:

> ```
>  ServerName otherdomain.com
>  ReWriteEngine on
>  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherdomain.com$ [NC]
>  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub1.domain.com/$1 [PT,L]
> ```

But it is giving me a 400 Bad request error.

How would I configure such a virtualhost?

Answer (score 0):

If the following doesn't do what you want, please explain why.

```
<Virtualhost ...>
  ServerName sub1.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /www/sub1
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost ...>
  Servername otherdomain.com
  DocumentRoot /www/sub1
</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: The subdomains on domain.com are created dynamically (my database stores which subdomains exist), that's why I'm using ServerAlias *.domain.com. There is no physical document root for every subdomain.